# Explode array three times

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching, explode

I have a string and I would like to explode with three differents patterns. The string looks like to :

```
country:00/00/00->link:00/00/00->link2
country2:00/00/00->link3:00/00/00->link4
```

I would like to get the differents parts of this two strings. The two lines are separated by a **/n**, the dates are separated by **:** and the link associated to date are separated with a **->**

At the beginning I explode by the line break

```
$var = explode("\n", $var);
```

but when I tried to explode again this string, I get an error : *preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given*

How can I get the different parts ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you don't seem to be using `preg_split()` how do you get this error?

Comment: `explode` returns an array. You'd have to use `join` before feeding it into `preg_split`.

Comment: @JohnConde Ooops that's true, I tried with preg_split too.

$var = explode("\n", $var);
$var2 = preg_split("/:/", $var);

and it returns this error.

Comment: @remyabel What part of the array I should join in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/rswOiU)

Instead of using `preg_split`, consider using `preg_match`. You can write it as one big regex.

```php
<?php

// Implicit newline. Adding \n would make an empty spot in the array
$str = "country:00/00/00->link:00/00/00->link2
country2:00/00/00->link3:00/00/00->link4";

$arr = split("\n", $str);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
preg_match("/^(\w+)\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)->(\w+)\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)->(\w+)/", $arr[$i], $matches);

print_r($matches);
}

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => country:00/00/00->link:00/00/00->link2
    [1] => country
    [2] => 00/00/00
    [3] => link
    [4] => 00/00/00
    [5] => link2
)
Array
(
    [0] => country2:00/00/00->link3:00/00/00->link4
    [1] => country2
    [2] => 00/00/00
    [3] => link3
    [4] => 00/00/00
    [5] => link4
)
```

**EDIT**

In your comment, you're posting dates with 4 digits, whereas in your question, they only had 2 digits.

Therefore you need to change the regex to:

`/^(\w+)\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)->(\w+)\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)->(\w+)/`

Comment: When I used your string, it works perfectly, but when I add my variable, there are nothing in the $matches var.

Before doing nothing: `string(82) "Paris:10/10/1000->link:10/10/1000->link
Londres:10/10/2000->link:20/20/2000->link"`  
After the first split : `array(2) { [0]=> string(40) "Paris:10/10/1000->link:10/10/1000->link " [1]=> string(41) "Londres:10/10/2000->link:20/20/2000->link" }`  
and finally nothing more : `array(0) { } array(0) { }`

Comment: Yes, that's sure, and I didn't notice it. Anyway, big thanks.

Comment: One more question, when I'm out of the for loop, it return only one array, not the two, why ?

Comment: @Jeremdsgn `preg_match` modifies `$matches`. You need to store them in a separate array.

Comment: How can I make optionnal the date part ? because when I put only one date/link, it doesn't work anymore. I can add more date/link if I want, not only two. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jeremdsgn Post that as a separate question. I'm not that good with regex.

Comment: Ok, I will make some searches. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `preg_match_all`:

```
<?php
    $data =<<<ENDDATA
country:00/00/00->link:00/00/00->link2
country2:00/00/00->link3:00/00/00->link4
ENDDATA;

    preg_match_all('#(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})->(.[^:\n]+)#', $data, $matches);

    print_r($matches);
```

Gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00/00/00->link
            [1] => 00/00/00->link2
            [2] => 00/00/00->link3
            [3] => 00/00/00->link4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00/00/00
            [1] => 00/00/00
            [2] => 00/00/00
            [3] => 00/00/00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => link
            [1] => link2
            [2] => link3
            [3] => link4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that after using explode first time, it is turning into an array and explode function connat explode an array. You need to use a loop probablr for loop that targets array elemets then use explode function on those elements and you will have it.
See example Below:

```
<?php
$val="abc~~~def~~~ghi@@@@jkl~~~mno~~~pqr@@@stu~~~vwx~~~yz1";
$val=explode("@@@@", $val);
//result will be
$valWillBe=array(3) {
[0]=>'abc~~~def~~~ghi',
[1]=>'jkl~~~mno~~~pqr',
[2]=>'stu~~~vwx~~~yz1'
}

//if you want to explode again you use a loop
for($r=0; $r<sizeof($val); $r++){
$val[$r]=explode("~~~", $val[$r]);
}
//now you have your string exploded all in places.

?>
```